# Embedding a Secured Grafana into Web Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, basic-authentication

I want to embed Grafana into my web application using AngularJS. The goal is, when user is in my application, she should be able to click on a button and load the Grafana UI. In itself, this is an easy task. To do this, I have apache  proxying Grafana and returning any necessary CORS headers. The apache reverse proxy config is as follows:

```
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, Authorization, accept, client-security-token"


    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
```

All works perfectly fine when no security is involved. The  following code is a simple HTML/Javascript that shows what I am doing:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.11/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<body >
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $sce) {

    $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
            console.log(src);
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(src);
    }

    $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'http://grafana-host.com',

    }).success(function(response) {
            $("#test").attr('src', 'http://grafana-host.com')
            $("#test").contents().find('html').html(response);

    }).error(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
    });
});
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<iframe id="test" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

The challenge now is that once logged in into my application, user should not have to log in into Grafana again.

To resolve this issue, I set up Grafana to use Basic Auth. My goal is for my web app to pass basic auth to Grafana via the browser. Basically, when the user clicks on the button to open Grafana, I would issue a request via AngularJS. This request would include the required Authorization header to load Grafana. To do this, I augment the above code segment with the http blog after the url field:

```
            headers : {
               'Authorization' : 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='
            }
```

Also, in the success callback function, I replace the first instruction with:

```
  $("#test").attr('src',"data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(response))
```

Unfortunately, I do not seem to be able to get this to work.

I know this should work because I can simulate this behavior with ModHeader extension of  Chrome browser. If I put the following header in ModHeader: Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=, it loads Grafana from  without need to log in. And if I remove the Authorization header, I am prompted for login name and password again.

The grafana changes are pretty simple:

```
[auth.basic]
enabled = true
```

What am I missing? My guess is this is an AngularJS/Javascript thing.

Comment: What is the point in securing grafana when you can 'attack' it using the proxy URL ?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your question. But to the extent that I understand, let me try to answer it. The proxy serves other purposes than securing Grafana. In my post, securing refers to providing authentication in an integrated environment.

Comment: @Klaus did you manage to get that to work eventually?

Comment: try selenium to login in to grafana in backend. So, the user see your login window and redirected to grafana dashboards.(just an idea).Im going to try the same myself, bcoz im doing something similar

Answer (score 6):

Don't know if this is an option at the time the question was written, but we're doing this quite successfully by injecting an API token for authorization (http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/auth/).

Comment: I thought that you can't use API Tokens to authenticate the UI?

Comment: Authenticating via the UI simply gives you a session cookie that allows you to access the various back-end API endpoints. Passing a token with your API requests  gets you the same functionality.