# Integrating Grafana into a web app

Tags: influxdb, grafana

A little background, I have been working with BCI (brain computer interface) and  multi channel EEG to monitor brain activity. When the user starts a session with the BCI cap on, the raw data streaming from each channel is stored into Influxdb.

I can visualize this data in real time which I successfully managed to achieve by integrating my database in Influxdb with Grafana as shown below for Channel 1

[image: EEG data for Channel 1]

However, my final aim is to create a web app where a user can login and see their current streaming session in real time or any of the previous sessions. The problem with Grafana is, it is not easy to integrate/embed with an existing web app. I looked into [Embed Panel](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/sharing/) but this enables me to add only a snapshot of the graph whereas I need it to be in real time where the data is continuously streamed to the chart.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you not just iframe grafana into your webapp? Like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583712/embedding-a-secured-grafana-into-web-application You might run into auth problems that you can solve like this: https://blog.raintank.io/authproxy-howto-use-external-authentication-handlers-with-grafana/

Comment: @Corleone Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm finding myself in a similar situation.

Comment: @ascu Unfortunately no, but I used external charting libraries (like Smoothie Charts, d3.js) to create my own charts

Answer (score 20):

Grafana does not have a "javascript library" which can be loaded into a page to recreate panels in an external web app ([relevant github issue here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/2122)).

If you are willing to use something other than grafana, you can connect to influxdb using a js driver like [influxdb-nodejs](https://github.com/vicanso/influxdb-nodejs) or [influent](https://github.com/gobwas/influent) to get the data and then use a plotting library (eg [flot](https://www.flotcharts.org/), [plotly](https://plot.ly/plotly-js-scientific-d3-charting-library/), [d3](https://d3js.org/), [smoothie charts](http://smoothiecharts.org/)) to re-create the charts. This would be the typical approach to the problem, but it does require a more development time on your part.

If you do want to use grafana, however, you can now [embed a grafana panel](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/reference/share_panel/#embed-panel) into an external app using an iframe like so:

```
<iframe 
    src="https://snapshot.raintank.io/dashboard-solo/snapshot/y7zwi2bZ7FcoTlB93WN7yWO4aMiz3pZb?from=1493369923321&to=1493377123321&panelId=4" 
    width="650" height="300" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I just clicked on the panel -> there's a button "Share" -> tab "Embed" - and you have the `iframe` tag that you can copy-paste into your website.